# Swift optional protocol requirements

Tags: swift, protocols

I have the following protocols declared.

```
protocol TypeAProtocol {
...
}

protocol TypeBProtocol {
...
}

protocol SomeProtocol {
    associatedtype TypeA: TypeAProtocol
    associatedtype TypeB: TypeBProtocol

    var objA: TypeA? { get set }
    var objB: TypeB? { get set }
}
```

Now if I want to create a class that implements `SomeProtocol`, I would have done this

```
class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    var objA: ClassOfTypeAProtocol?
    var objB: ClassOfTypeBProtocol?
}
```

The problem I am facing now is, I want to be able to create classes that implement `SomeProtocol` without `var objB: TypeB? { get set }`. I want `objB` to be optional. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have a look at the [Optional protocol requirements part of the Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID284). However, be aware that associated type requirements cannot be marked optional.

Comment: `protocol HasAProtocol { type TypeA...; var objA: TypeA {get set} }; protocol HasBothProtocol: HasAProtocol { type TypeB...; var objB: TypeB { get set }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Objective-C you can declare an optional member (method/computed property) in a protocol.

In pure Swift this is not possible unless you use the @objc annotation (but in this case structs and enums won't be able to conform to your protocol so it's not the best way to go).

So, how can you solve your problem?

### Let's split SomeProtocol into 3 protocols

These are your protocols

```
protocol TypeAProtocol { }
protocol TypeBProtocol { }
protocol SomeProtocol {
    associatedtype TypeA: TypeAProtocol
    associatedtype TypeB: TypeBProtocol

    var objA: TypeA? { get set }
    var objB: TypeB? { get set }
}
```

Now we'll split `SomeProtocol` into 3 protocols

```
protocol SomeProtocolBase {
    associatedtype TypeA: TypeAProtocol
    associatedtype TypeB: TypeBProtocol
}
protocol SomeProtocolPartA: SomeProtocolBase {
    var objA: TypeA? { get set }
}

protocol SomeProtocolPartB: SomeProtocolBase {
    var objB: TypeB? { get set }
}
```

### That's it

Now you can write

```
class ClassOfTypeAProtocol: TypeAProtocol { }
class ClassOfTypeBProtocol: TypeBProtocol { }

class SomeClass: SomeProtocolPartA {
    typealias TypeA = ClassOfTypeAProtocol
    typealias TypeB = ClassOfTypeBProtocol
    var objA: ClassOfTypeAProtocol?
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luca! Your suggestion to split `SomeProtocol` maybe the solution.